# How to show that $x$ and $y$ intercept are both zero?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a question from my book I have, there is this question:

> A linear function has equation $y = −2x$.
>
> Show that the $x$-intercept and the $y$-intercept are both zero.

How do I show they are both zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $y = f(x)$. The interception with the $y$-axis is given by $f (0) = -2 \cdot 0 = 0.$

The interception with the $x$-axis is a solution of the equation $y = 0$, i.e., $-2x = 0$. Dividing by $-2$ yields $x = 0$.